# Vertical scrolling in Windows 8 FlipView

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-store-apps, winjs

Is it possible to do a vertical scroll in a WinJS FlipView?
It seems like the FlipView is blocking the scroll event?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not tried this with a FlipView but on a ListView you have to add the win-interactive css class to elements in your itemTemplate in order to interact with them. You could try that. Also, showing some code might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that the win-interactive css class will allow for vertical scrolling in a FlipView. To test, you can set up a FlipView and use the following as it's itemTemplate:

```
<div id="simple_ItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <div class="overlaidItemTemplate">
        <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll">
            <div class="win-interactive" style="height: 1000px; background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 100%)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting content into a FlipView control that requires scrolling, but the FlipView orientation is horizontal, you may want to review the [guidelines for panning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465310.aspx) to ensure that your interaction pattern is consistent with recommendations, and won't end up being confusing or difficult to use.